# How to keep uniswap v3 getPool function from reverting in Remix

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, uniswap

I am trying to write a contract that can fetch a uniswap v3 pool address for different pairs of tokens. To start, I just hardcoded in some addresses to see what would happen.

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0; 

import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/IQuoter.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Factory.sol";

contract FactoryConsts {
    IQuoter public constant uniswapQuoter = IQuoter(0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6);
    IUniswapV3Factory public constant uniFactory = IUniswapV3Factory(0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984);
}

contract Swap is FactoryConsts {
    address private constant DAI = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;
    address private constant WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
    
    function getPoolAddress() external view returns (address) {
        address pool = uniFactory.getPool(DAI, WETH, 3000);
        return pool;
    }
}
```

I got the token addresses from info.uniswap.org. When I run this function in Remix, the transaction reverts and says

```
call to Swap.getPoolAddress errored: VM error: revert.
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

I am unable to debug this because the uniswap v3 factory contract provides an interface for this function but no implementation. This is the interface:

```
    /// @notice Returns the pool address for a given pair of tokens and a fee, or address 0 if it does not exist
    /// @dev tokenA and tokenB may be passed in either token0/token1 or token1/token0 order
    /// @param tokenA The contract address of either token0 or token1
    /// @param tokenB The contract address of the other token
    /// @param fee The fee collected upon every swap in the pool, denominated in hundredths of a bip
    /// @return pool The pool address
    function getPool(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint24 fee
    ) external view returns (address pool);
```

available at https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Factory.sol.

Comment: Hi AndrewKing! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Take a look a the code verified in Etherscan https://etherscan.io/address/0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984#code. If I'm not wrong getPool is a mapping.

Comment: I see. I'm new to solidity. So when the implementation contract specifies that the mapping getPool is overriding the function getPool, are the three parameters in the function interpreted as three sequential map accesses? Additionally, is there a way that this access would fail on a testnet but not mainnet?

Comment: It is declared as `mapping(address => mapping(address => mapping(uint24 => address))) public override getPool`. It has three parameters: address, address, uint24. It should work, I'd check if you are connected to mainnet.

Comment: Closing the loop, the issue was that the pool is not staked on the testnet I was looking at. Running the code on mainnet returned a valid address.